# How to handle progress update using ReactiveX Observables/Subjects?

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, observable, progress, reactivex

I'm writing an Angular app which uses the ReactiveX API to handle asynchronous operations. I used the API before in an Android project and I really like how it simplifies concurrent task handling. But there is one thing which I'm not sure how to solve in a right way.

How to update observer from an ongoing task? The task in this case will take time to load/create a complex/large object and I'm able to return intermediate progress, but not the object itself. The observable can only return one dataType. Therefor I know two possibilities.

1. Create an object which has a progress field and a data field. This object can be simply returned with Observable.onNext(object). The progress field will update on every onNext, while the data field is empty until the last onNext, which will set it to the loaded value.
2. Create two observables, a data observable and a progress observable. The observer hast to subscribe to the progress observable for progress updates and to the data observable to be notified when the data is finally loaded/created. These can also be optionally be zipped together for one subscription.

I used both techniques, they both work, but I want to know if there is a unified standard, a clean way, how to solve this task. It can, of course, as well be a completly new one. Im open for every solution.

Comment: Option 2 is a little bit cleaner, but you could certainly do option one using `Either` or `Pair` to compose the two kinds into a unified data type.

Comment: What are you doing with the progress updates? The second solution is prone to race conditions between receiving the last progress updates and receiving the data object, so if your logic is sensitive to that ordering, you might not be able to use it.

Comment: The progress update is mainly used to show a progress bar to the user. One use case is iterating through a directory structure, reading the header of every DICOM (Medical Image) file in the directory, and create a map between Series ID and images. Another use case is creating a 3d Mesh from Volume data by iterating through a volume. I also find it harder to keep track of event execution in the second solution, even though the progress is just a visual indicator, so race conditions are not that critical.

Comment: If your only use is graphical feedback, you might consider subscribing to a Timer in the view renderer and check progress through the file iterator object state (e.g. maintain a stack of iterated files). This frees the iterator to maintain its single responsibility: returning the singular result from the operation akin to a `Promise<TResult>`.

Comment: Correction: *consider subscribing to an `Interval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After careful consideration I use a
solution similar to option two in my question.
The main observable is concerned with the actual result of
the operation.
A http request in this case, but the File iteration example is similar.
It is returned by the "work" function.

A second Observer/Subscriber can be added through a function parameter. This subscriber is concerned only with
the progress information. This way all operations are nullsafe and no type checks are needed.

A second version of the work function, without the progress Observer,
can be used if no progress UI update is needed.

```
export class FileUploadService {

 doWork(formData: FormData, url: string): Subject<Response> {
    return this.privateDoWork(formData, url, null);
 }

 doWorkWithProgress(formData: FormData, url: string, progressObserver: Observer<number>): Subject<Response> {
    return this.privateDoWork(formData, url, progressObserver);
 }

 private privateDoWork(formData: FormData, url: string, progressObserver: Observer<number> | null): Subject<Response> {

     return Observable.create(resultObserver => {
     let xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open("POST", url);

     xhr.onload = (evt) => {
         if (progressObserver) {
            progressObserver.next(1);
            progressObserver.complete();
            }
         resultObserver.next((<any>evt.target).response);
         resultObserver.complete()
     };
     xhr.upload.onprogress = (evt) => {
         if (progressObserver) {
            progressObserver.next(evt.loaded / evt.total);
         }

     };
     xhr.onabort = (evt) => resultObserver.error("Upload aborted by user");
     xhr.onerror = (evt) => resultObserver.error("Error");

     xhr.send(formData);
     });
 }
```

Here is a call of the function including the progress Subscriber. With this solution the caller of the upload function must
create/handle/teardown the progress subscriber.

```
 this.fileUploadService.doWorkWithProgress(this.chosenSerie.formData, url, new Subscriber((progress) => console.log(progress * 100)).subscribe(
    (result) => console.log(result),
    (error) => console.log(error),
    () => console.log("request Completed")
    );
```

Overall I prefered this solution to a "Pair" Object with a single subscription. There is no null handling nececcary, and
I got a clean seperation of concerns.

The example is written in Typescript, but similar solutions should be possible with other ReactiveX implementations.